# spyder installation, no pip, no conda activate

Tags: python-3.x, pip, spyder, miniconda

How do i install packages in spyder?

I installed python on windows 10, default installation.

I installed spyder, default installation.

I tried `pip install selenium` in the spyder terminal :`"No module named pip"`

I changed the interpreter to `C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe`. I got this error `"... doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed ...`"

From cmd i sent `python pip install spyder-kernels==2.5.*`. installation successful, spyder still displays the same message.

Ok, so let's try miniconda. Installed miniconda, default installation.

from cmd: `cd C:\users\myuser\miniconda3\`   (the exe file is name _conda.exe, i copied it and renamed conda.exe)

```
conda create -n spyder-env -y
```

executed without error, and i find it in conda env list
then i try

```
conda activate spyder-env
```

Error `conda: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate'`
tried `conda init cmd.exe`
Nope

```
WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: C:\Users\djmer\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI17722
ERROR during elevated execution.
```

Uninstalled everything and tried again, same results.